# How to fix sonar issue "Disable access to external entities in XML parsing" in Junits

Tags: java, junit, xml-parsing

from what i have understood that in order to get rid of the sonar issue "Disable access to external entities in XML parsing" , we need to have the following code in place

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

But when i do this, my JUnits which invokes this code fails saying

> Failed to read schema document 'myschema.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the
> accessExternalSchema property.

So how can we get around this? If we fix sonar issue, our Junit fails .

I also tried inistiasing the factory like below, but no change in error

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = new com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new *Transformer* object using the *newDefaultInstance()* method which is not flagged by sonar. See below:

```
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance();
    transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
```

The main difference between the two methods is that *newDefaultInstance()* returns a default *TransformerFactory* instance, while *newInstance()* allows you to specify a specific implementation class for the *TransformerFactory*.

In other words, *newDefaultInstance()* returns an instance of the default implementation of the *TransformerFactory* that is provided by the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) being used.